# Editing data in Google Spreedsheet using Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to know the commend used to change the value of data on spacific row, colum 
from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0
or from " " to 1 or 2
as you can see i only need some basic info and i think my code then would run without any problems. 
here is my code so far

```
//start of accepted or rejected
function acceptreject()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  for(var k = 0; k < numRows;k++)
  {  
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
    {
      var row = data[i];

      var email_address = row[3];
      var accepted_rejected = row[8];
      var email_sent = row[9];
    }
    if(accepted_rejected = "1")
    {
      if(email_sent = "0")
      {
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email_address, ":D You Got Accepted  :D", "");
        email_sent = "1";
      }
      else if(email_sent = "1")
      {

      }
      else
      {

      }
    }
    else if(accepted_rejected = "0")
    {
      if(email_sent = "0")
      {
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email_address, ":'( You Got Rejected  :'(", "We are sorry but your place got filled. Try again the next recruitment don’t forget to follow the technologies and upgrade yourself by self-learning. Thank you for cooperation and understanding!");
        email_sent = "1";
      }
      else if(email_sent = "1")
      {

      }
      else
      {

      }
    }
    else
    {
      GmailApp.sendEmail("name@somewhere.com","New Recruitment ;)", "New Recruitment Need Appointment for Interview");
    }
  }
}
//end of accepted or rejected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to update `data` in your loop when necessary and at the end re-write `data` to the sheet so that its values are updated.

Try like this :

```
function acceptreject()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  for(var k = 0; k < numRows;k++)
  {  
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
    {
      var row = data[i];

      var email_address = row[3];
      var accepted_rejected = row[8];
      var email_sent = row[9];
    }
    if(accepted_rejected = "1")
    {
      if(email_sent = "0")
      {
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email_address, ":D You Got Accepted  :D", "");
        email_sent = "1";
        row[9]="1"
      }
      else if(email_sent = "1")
      {

      }
      else
      {

      }
    }
    else if(accepted_rejected = "0")
    {
      if(email_sent = "0")
      {
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email_address, ":'( You Got Rejected  :'(", "We are sorry but your place got filled. Try again the next recruitment don’t forget to follow the technologies and upgrade yourself by self-learning. Thank you for cooperation and understanding!");
        email_sent = "1";
        row[9]="1"
      }
      else if(email_sent = "1")
      {

      }
      else
      {

      }
    }
    else
    {
      GmailApp.sendEmail("name@somewhere.com","New Recruitment ;)", "New Recruitment Need Appointment for Interview");
    }
  }

  sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: it's working :D
thanks a lot 
but for some reason he only send the you got accepted message even when accepted_rejected = "0"
it still sends you got accepted

Comment: I did not check the logic, only the sheet update. Reread your if/else structure... btw, thx for accepting.

Comment: thanks alot <br/>
just found out what was wrong plus your helpful info about the sheet update :D